# Show that every primitive Pythagorean triple is of the form $(2 \lambda \mu, \lambda ^ 2 - \mu ^ 2, \lambda ^ 2 + \mu ^ 2)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, pythagorean-triples

I am working through the book "Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach" by Garrity et al., and I want somebody to check my work.  I feel like I don't have a good grasp on projective geometry and it's all a little weird to me.  Constructive feedback would be appreciated.

We are considering the rational points of the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, and we are denoting the rational points by the set:

$$C(\mathbb{Q}) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$$

We consider a map $\tilde{\psi}: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow C(\mathbb{Q})$ defined by $\tilde{\psi}(\lambda) = \left(\frac{2 \lambda}{\lambda^2 + 1},\frac{\lambda^2 - 1}{\lambda^2 + 1}\right)$, then extend this function to the projective line by considering $\psi: \mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow C(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{Q})$ defined by:

$$\psi(\lambda : \mu) = (2 \lambda \mu : \lambda^2 - \mu^2: \lambda^2 + \mu^2)$$

We are then asked to show:

(1) Show that $\psi: \mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow C(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{Q})$ is onto.

(2) Show that every primitive Pythagorean triple is of the form $(2 \lambda \mu, \lambda^2 - \mu^2, \lambda^2 + \mu^2)$

**Attempted solution**

To show part (1) I am trying to show that for every $(x:y:1) \in C(\mathbb{Q})$, there exists some $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\psi(\lambda:\mu) = (x:y:1)$.  This is equivalent to saying that for $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, there exist rationals $\lambda, \mu$ with:

$$(2 \lambda \mu : \lambda^2 - \mu^2: \lambda^2 + \mu^2) = (x:y:1).$$

By the definition of projective space, this means there exists $t \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that:

$$2 \lambda \mu = tx$$
$$\lambda^2 - \mu^2 = ty$$
$$\lambda^2 + \mu^2 = t$$

Adding the second and third expressions together we obtain:

$$2 \lambda^2 = ty + tz \implies \lambda^2 = \frac{t(y+1)}{2}$$

Similarly, subtracting equation 2 from equation 3 yields:

$$2 \mu^2 = tz-ty \implies \mu^2 = \frac{t(1-y)}{2}$$

Dividing these by the first equation gives:

$$\frac{\lambda^2}{2 \lambda \mu} = \frac{y + 1}{2x} \implies \lambda = \frac{y + 1}{x}\mu \implies \mu = \frac{x}{y + 1} \lambda.$$

Then we have:

$$\psi\left(\frac{y + 1}{x}: 1\right) = \left(2\left( \frac{y + 1}{x}\right): \left(\frac{y + 1}{x}\right)^2 - 1: \left(\frac{y + 1}{x}\right)^2  + 1\right) = (x : y : 1)$$

Where I have omitted division by the final coordinate in the middle and used the fact that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

For part (2), suppose $x, y, z$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple, so that it cannot be obtain by multiplying by a previous Pythagorean triple.  We have $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, so in other words $\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^2 = 1$ and $\left(\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z}\right) \in C(\mathbb{Q})$.  By the surjectivity of $\psi$ there exists $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Q}$ with:

$$(2 \lambda \mu : \lambda^2 - \mu^2: \lambda^2 + \mu^2) = \left(\frac{x}{z}:\frac{y}{z}:1\right) = (x:y:z).$$

Let $\lambda = \frac{a}{b}, \mu = \frac{c}{d}$, and let $A = (bd)^2, B = ad, C = bc$. We have:

$$A (2\lambda\mu) = 2(ad)(bc) = 2BC$$
$$A (\lambda^2 - \mu^2) = B^2 - C^2$$
$$A (\lambda^2 + \mu^2) = B^2 + C^2$$

We can divide out factors of $B$ and $C$ until both are relatively prime, and then $(2BC, B^2 - C^2, B^2 + C^2$) will be a primitive Pythagorean triple (if it weren't primitive we can show by contradiction that $B$ and $C$ would have to share a factor after all, but honestly this write-up is getting long and I'm going to skip that detail, so if it's wrong just let me know and I'll give details about this part).  Then we have:

$$(2BC: B^2 - C^2: B^2 + C^2) = (2 \lambda \mu : \lambda^2 - \mu^2: \lambda^2 + \mu^2) = (x:y:z).$$

This means there is a $t = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with

$$2BC = tx$$
$$B^2 - C^2 = ty$$
$$B^2 + C^2 = tz$$

But a primitive pythagorean triple cannot be a rational multiple of another distinct pythagorean triple.  To see why, note that $t$ cannot be an integer greater than 1, so $q \neq 1$ if $p>1$ (otherwise the LHS would not be primitive). But since $tx$, $ty$, $tz$ must all be integers from the formulae above, then each of $x,y,z$ shares a factor of $q$, but this means that $(x,y,z)$ is not primitive, since $(\frac{x}{q}, \frac{y}{q}, \frac{z}{q})$ would then by a pythagorean triple.  Therefore $t = 1$ and $(x,y,z)$ has the form $(2BC, B^2 - C^2, B^2 + C^2)$. $\square$

Please let me know if my general reasoning is OK.  Thanks.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.